# If$x \equiv y\pmod n$ then prove that $(x,n)=(y,n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given: $x \equiv y\pmod n$
To prove:$(x,n)=(y,n)$ 
where, $(a,b)$ means HCF/GCD of both $a$ and $b$. 
I don't know where to start the solution of the problem, please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I think instead of lcm there should be gcd

Comment: $x \equiv y\pmod n$ means that $x = y+kn$ for some integer $k$. Now compute $(x,n) = (y+kn, n)$.

Comment: How to prove that taking the HCF of both sides will be OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proved using just the definitions.

Let $d_x=\gcd(x,n)$ and $d_y=\gcd(y,n)$.

Since $x \equiv y \pmod{n}$, we can write $x-y=nk$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Now, $d_x$ divides $x$ and $nk$, so it also divides $x-nk=y$. Since $d_y$ is the $greatest$ common factor of $y$ and $n$, $d_x \mid y,n \implies d_x \mid d_y$.

Similarly, $d_y$ divides $y$ and $nk$, so it also divides $y-nk=x$. Since $d_x$ is the $greatest$ common factor of $x$ and $n$, $d_y \mid x,n \implies d_y \mid d_x$.

Thus, we have two positive integers $d_y$ and $d_x$ such that $d_y\mid d_x$ and $d_x \mid d_y$, which means that $d_x=d_y$.

Answer (score 1):

$x=y(modn)$ means $x=y+kn$. Now let the $gcd(x,n)=d_1, \text{then } d_1|x \text{ and } d_1|n.$

So, $x=d_1c_1$ and $n=d_1c_2$ for some $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{R}.$ Substituting $x$ in $x=y+kn$ we have $y=d_1c_1-kd_1c_2=d_1(c_1-kc_2).$

This implies that $d_1|y$, and since $d_1|n$. Then, we have $gcd(y,n)=gcd(x,n)$ or $(y,n)=(x,n).$

Comment: Your argument only proves that $gcd(x,n)$ divides $y$ (or you're skipping *many* steps in your last line).

Comment: @ColdNumber, remember the $gcd(x,n)$ also divides $n$ from $x=y(modn)$.

Comment: Yes. But that's not enough to conclude the gcds are equal.

Comment: @ColdNumber You are right, we have to show that if there is any integer that divides $y$ and $n$ then it must divide $gcd(x,n)=d_1$.

Comment: Well, that's true by definition. You showed that $\gcd(x,n)$ divides $y$ and $n$, so you can deduce that $\gcd(x,n)$ divides $\gcd(y,n)$. Then you do pretty much the same thing to show $\gcd(y,n)$ divides $\gcd(x,n)$, and then you can conclude that they're equal *because* they are both positive. Otherwise, you could have one equal to the negative of the other.